# Overriding the default widget class names in gwt

Tags: java, css, twitter-bootstrap, gwt

Gwt uses standardized css class names such as

```
.gwt-Image 
.gwt-Button
```

and so on. This prevents me from using these classes with popular css frameworks such as bootstrap.

Is there a way I can override these default style names and use bootstrap or foundation compliant class names ?

Comment: If you just want to use Bootstrap with GWT, then I'd recommend using [gwtbootstrap3](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/) or [gwtbootstrap](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/) (uses version 2.x). You'll get all the benefits of Bootstrap packed nicely into Java classes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using LESS as a CSS Preprocessor, you could extend the bootstrap mixins to your GWT classes

**Ex :**

```
.gwt-Button {
    .btn(); //This is the bootstrap mixin for buttons
}
```

**Renders to :**

```
    .gwt-Button{
       display: inline-block;
       margin-bottom: 0;
       font-weight: normal;
       text-align: center;
       vertical-align: middle;
       touch-action: manipulation;
       cursor: pointer;
       background-image: none;
       border: 1px solid transparent;
       white-space: nowrap;
       padding: 6px 12px;
       font-size: 14px;
       line-height: 1.42857143;
       border-radius: 4px;
       -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
       -ms-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;
    }
```

It's a little time consuming, but it allows you to have everything in your CSS

Comment: Although @Andrei-volgin gave a very quick and technically accurate answer I appreciate your specifics since it helps me understand how to bring in bootstrap or other such css frameworks into play.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but mixing two very different CSS frameworks is definitely not easy. CSS includes the word _cascading_ for a reason, and you have to look at how all the other CSS rules may affect any particular element. I believe it is much easier to go with one framework *or* the other, and then customize it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can add your own class names with the addStyleName method:

From their Stock Widget example:

```
// Add styles to elements in the stock list table.
stocksFlexTable.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(0, "watchListHeader");
```

Just add the class names used in Bootstrap to the relevant elements.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/style.html

Answer (score 0):

All widgets have setStyleName method. You can call it everywhere you creating a widget. Or you can extend used GWT classes and call setStyleName in the constructor.

```
public class Button extends com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button { 
     public Button() {
          setStyleName("my-stale-name");
     }
```

}